# TCP Client reads first message but not the rest

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am trying to send a request to an existing server solution and write out the results.  The server is sending a total of 4 messages with my particular request but the number of messsages back can vary depending on the initial query.

I am able to successfully send the query to the server but when it comes to reading the response i can only read one message.  The server logs show that 4 were sent back.

Please help.

```
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server_textbox.Text);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0], port);
        string data = String.Empty;
        testclient = new TcpClient(server_textbox.Text, port);
        testclient.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024;
        testclient.SendBufferSize = 1024;
        NetworkStream netStream = testclient.GetStream();
        Byte[] message_byte = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(msg2);
        netStream.Write(message_byte, 0, message_byte.Length);

        Byte[] returnMessage = new byte[1024];
        Int32 totalBytesReceived = 0;
        Int32 bytesReceived = 0;
        try
        {

            while ((bytesReceived = netStream.Read(returnMessage, totalBytesReceived, returnMessage.Length)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;
                data += "\n" + ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(returnMessage);

                bytesReceived = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
        result_box.Text += data;
        netStream.Close();
        testclient.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Eric beat me to it, what he said.

Comment: How many bytes are you sending? Because you pass in totalBytesReceived as offset to Read(),  you won't be able to ever read more than the 1024 bytes you specify as the array size.

Comment: 1024 is the max size i can be receiving its hard coded on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that all your messages are read in the first `Read`. When the server replies, all the data gets stuck in the windows receive buffer and gets read all at once.

I would recommend using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), which is more or less mandatory when doing network programming. You'll be able to see the 4 messages coming back from the server as at least 4 different tcp packets.

Comment: I am looking at the data the server is sending back and i am getting something very odd.  I am getting 3 messages pushed back to me.  The first two messages contain what i expect and the final message contains all four messages.